# NSString variable available throughout program

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

I have this line of code:

```
NSString *dateString = [self.dates objectAtIndex:row];
```

that gets set when a user selects a row in a picker. I'd like to have this code available everywhere and not just in the picker select area. Other wise I get a "dateString" is undeclared error message of course.

how would i go about doing this?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use the singleton design pattern ? To me, it seems to be a cleaner solution that solutions posted above.

### VariableStore.m

```
#import "VariableStore.h"

@implementation VariableStore

@synthesize dateString;

+ (VariableStore *)sharedInstance
{
    static VariableStore *myInstance = nil;

    if (nil == myInstance)
        myInstance  = [[[self class] alloc] init];

    return myInstance;
}
@end
```

### VariableStore.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface VariableStore : NSObject
{
    NSString *dateString;
}

+ (VariableStore *)sharedInstance;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *dateString;

@end
```

### AnyClassWhereYouWantToUseYourVariable.h

```
#import "VariableStore.h"
```

### AnyClassWhereYouWantToUseYourVariable.m

```
NSLog("dateString = %@", [VariableStore sharedInstance].dateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple, but not very elegant solution is to use NSUserDefaults.

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// saving an NSString
[prefs setObject:@"TextToSave" forKey:@"keyToLookupString"];
[prefs synchronize];

// getting an NSString
NSString *myString = [prefs stringForKey:@"keyToLookupString"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Define as a global variable in your interface file(.h) file. If you want to use in other class as well make the property and synthesize it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. You can save the entire string. 
Just create NSString object of

in (YourDelegare.h) file

NSString * dateString;

in (YourDelegare.m) file

```
  -(void) saveMyState 
 {
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[prefs setObject:dateString forKey:@"dateString"];  

[prefs synchronize];
 }


- (void) retrieveMyState
{
//Retrieving

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
dateString = [prefs stringForKey:@"dateString"];


 }
```

just call these methods wherever required.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can declare that variable in your delegate file.

In `yourdelegate.h`:

```
NSString *yourString;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *yourString;
```

In `yourdelegate.m`:

```
@synthesize yourString;
```

In `viewcontrolller.h`:

```
yourdelegate *appDelegate;
```

In `viewcontrolller.m`:

```
appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];  // in viewDidLoad
appDelegate.yourString = [self.dates objectAtIndex:row];  // where ever you need
```

And, like magic, it's a global variable now.